# Error: error finding vApp: [ENF] entity not found

Tags: vmware

I am trying to create the VM in vmware vcloud director 10 using terraform VCD provider.

Version

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    vcd = {
      source  = "vmware/vcd"
      version = "3.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Main code:

```
resource "vcd_vapp" "vms" {
  name     = "apatsev-vapp"
  power_on = "true"

}

resource "vcd_vapp_vm" "vm1" {
  vapp_name     = "apatsev_vm"
  name          = "apatsev1"
  catalog_name  = "CentOS"
  template_name = "CentOS7_64-bit"
  memory        = 2048
  cpus          = 2
  cpu_cores     = 1

  depends_on = [vcd_vapp.vms]

}
```

Error:

```
Error: error finding vApp: [ENF] entity not found

  on main.tf line 28, in resource "vcd_vapp_vm" "vm1":
  28: resource "vcd_vapp_vm" "vm1" {
```

How fix error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked code:

```
resource "vcd_vapp" "vms" {
  name     = "apatsev-vapp"
  power_on = "true"

}

resource "vcd_vapp_vm" "vm1" {
  vapp_name     = vcd_vapp.vms.name
  name          = "apatsev1"
  catalog_name  = "CentOS"
  template_name = "CentOS7_64-bit"
  memory        = 2048
  cpus          = 2
  cpu_cores     = 1

  depends_on = [vcd_vapp.vms]

}
```